# How to read songs on android 10 from external storage

Tags: java, android

[getting NullPointerException error when ever I try to read songs from external storage on android 10(Q) using File files[] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();,its returning an empty array,the app runs on android 9 and below, but it brings this error on android 10,anyone got an idea how to fix it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmXsx.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include the code (and error) as *text* in your question, along with explanation as to what you've tried in order to fix this and what happened. Questions that are just a  link to an image are rarely well received in Stack Overflow.

Comment: You would not get that exception if you checked `files` for `null`. Dont use that variable then. So its not returning an empty array but a null array.